# Does static block guarantee Eager loading

Tags: java, jboss7.x

I’ve a class that has register api where clients can register their implementation. If the clients call register in their implementation’s static block, does java/Jboss guarantee that class will be loaded eagerly and static block will be executed?

Comment: Java never loads classes eagerly.  Java classes are not loaded until the first time that they are accessed by executing code.  This forms the basis for the use of the Java Holder Class pattern to hold a static field that must be lazily initialized in a concurrent environment: the static field won't be initialized until the class is needed.

Comment: Also self-registration is horrific. JDBC used it, but that is from the early years when lots of bad ideas were tried out. / The one-arg `Class.forName` automatically initialises classes if that's what you were thinking of.